# load content into div

Tags: jquery

I have this very simple page with menu that contain three `<ul>`s and the content div: http://jsfiddle.net/vvqPN/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.subcontent:gt(0)').hide();
    $('#menu').on('click', 'li:not(.current) a', function () {
        $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.subcontent:visible').hide(600);
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.subcontent[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').show(600);
    });
});
```

In the page, when you click on the first `<ul>` the first content loads into the content div, then when you click the second `<ul>` the second content loads into the content div and the same thing for the third content.
The problem that I'm trying to solve is that when you scroll down in the page and try to click on any of the `<ul>`s the page automatically return to the top of the page.

Comment: Your anchor links are looking for an anchor defined as `#` which doesn't exist, thus, it sends you to the top of the document. You could specify `<a href="javascript:void(0)">` as the `href` of your anchor links, or you could do what @kunalbhat suggested below. I'd suggest @kunalbhat's answer because it is unobtrusive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `preventDefault();` to disable the default behavior of an anchor tag (linking to something).

```
$('#menu').on('click', 'li:not(.current) a', function (event) { //Add event
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```

Comment: what's the better solution, yours or the other one, and why? honestly

Comment: They are identical, mine was just first :P

Answer (score 1):

prevent the default click event of the anchor tag. Otherwise, the url is changed, and the page is sent to the top.

```
$('#menu').on('click', 'li:not(.current) a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HM633/

Comment: Is the page being reloaded, or is it just sending them to the top because the anchor tag doesn't exist?

Comment: what's the better solution, yours or the other one, and why? honestly

Comment: the only difference between mine and @kunalbhat is that he uses the full semantic `event` variable name, while i shorten mine to `e`. They are functionally exactly the same.

Comment: `event` is a global variable in Internet Explorer. Thus, as a cross browser way of handling events, you'll often see `function (e) { e = e || event; }` to get the event object as it's not always passed to the callback directly.